# Destruction error while implementing variant

Tags: c++, c++14

I am trying to rewrite the basis of `std::variant` because I must use a c++14 compiler (without std::variant) and I need a typesafe enum.

My code only works with fundamental types (ie `int`, `float`, `char *`, etc.) But when using `std::string` for example, I have issues with destruction.

Here is my code:

```
namespace utils
{
  namespace // private implementation
  {
    template<std::size_t Index, typename T, typename... Rest>
    struct can_construct_type : std::false_type {}; // End of recursion, T is not in Rest...

    template<std::size_t Index, typename T, typename First>
    struct can_construct_type<Index, T, First> : std::is_constructible<First, T>
    { // There is only one type remaining to check
      static constexpr std::size_t index = Index;
    };

    template<std::size_t Index, typename T, typename First, typename... Rest>
    struct can_construct_type<Index, T, First, Rest...> : std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_constructible<First, T>::value || can_construct_type<Index + 1, T, Rest...>::value>
    { // Main recursive loop. Check for First, then recursively for Rest...
      static constexpr std::size_t index = (std::is_constructible<First, T>::value ? Index : can_construct_type<Index + 1, T, Rest...>::index);
    };
  }

  template<typename T, typename... Types>
  using can_construct_type = can_construct_type<0, T, Types...>;
}


template<typename... Types>
class variant
{
  template<typename _Vp> friend void * __get_storage(_Vp &);

  using storage_t = std::aligned_union_t<0u, Types...>;
  storage_t m_storage;
  int m_type_index;

  /* creation of content */
  template<typename T> inline void set_value(T const & value)
  {
    new ((T *)std::addressof(m_storage)) T(value);
    m_type_index = utils::can_construct_type<T, Types...>::index;
  }

  /* destruction of content */
  inline void destroy_data(void) { invoke_destructor(m_type_index, std::addressof(m_storage)); }
  static void invoke_destructor(int type, storage_t * storage_address)
  {
    static const std::array<void(*)(storage_t *), sizeof...(Types)> destructors
    {
      std::addressof(invoke_destructor_impl<Types>)...
    };
    destructors[type](storage_address);
  }
  template<class T> static void invoke_destructor_impl(storage_t * storage_address)
  {
    T * pt = reinterpret_cast<T *>(storage_address);
    delete pt;
    //pt->~T(); // I tried delete or ->~T() but both crash
  }

public:
  variant() = delete;
  template<typename T> variant(T value)
  {
    set_value(value);
  }

  template<typename T> variant & operator=(T & value)
  {
    destroy_data();
    set_value(value);
    return *this;
  }

  ~variant()
  {
    destroy_data();
  }

  std::size_t index(void) const
  {
    return m_type_index;
  }
};

/* getter */
template<typename Variant> static void * __get_storage(Variant & var)
{
  return reinterpret_cast<void *>(std::addressof(var.m_storage));
}

template<typename T, typename... Types> T * get_if(variant<Types...> & var)
{
  return (var.index() == utils::contains_type<T, Types...>::index
    ? reinterpret_cast<T *>(__get_storage(var))
    : nullptr);
}

/* tests */
int main()
{
  variant<int, char *> var_test(42);
  int * value1 = get_if<int>(var_test);
  if (value1)
  {
    std::cout << *value1 << "\n"; // OK
  }

  var_test = _strdup("Hello !");
  char ** value2 = get_if<char *>(var_test);
  if (value2)
  {
    std::cout << *value2 << "\n"; // OK
  }

  variant<int, std::string> var_test_2(42);
  //var_test_2 = _strdup("Hello again !");
  var_test_2 = std::string("Hello again !");
  std::string * value3 = get_if<std::string>(var_test_2);
  if (value3)
  {
    std::cout << *value3 << "\n";
  }
  return 0; // it crashes when the destructor of var_test_2 is called
}
```

I put a full code example, but only the implementation of `variant` is important.

I suppose I badly used the `std::aligned_union` but I cannot figure where and how.

I get the error:

> Exception thrown at 0x00096370 in Test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xDDDDDDDD.

Update: it *seems* the destructor is called twice but I do not find why.

Comment: What are your "issues with destruction"?

Comment: @Carcigenicate updated

Comment: > I am trying to rewrite the basis of std::variant because I must use a c++14 compiler:

Use boost::variant?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo They do not want to use `boost` or other extern libraries in my company, unfortunately :/

Comment: you can check how many times your destructor is called by putting a breakpoint inside

Comment: @Boiethios so instead of using out of the box solutions tested by a large community over a lengthy span of time you have to reinvent the wheel and hope you do it right.

Comment: @bolov Do not worry, in a large part my answer come from gnu libc++ source and community (for example http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/141004/custom-basic-stdvariant )

Comment: @Boiethios yes, but nothing beats years of real-world testing. Don't get me wrong, I love to reinvent the wheel, the rush alone when you figure some clever trick is worth it. But that is for my personal learning and *playing*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assignment operator is wrong:

```
template<typename T> variant & operator=(T & value)
```

This only accepts lvalues, but you try to assign an rvalue:

```
var_test_2 = std::string("Hello again !");
```

Instead of calling your custom assignment operator, it calls the implicitly defined copy assignment operator by constructing a temporary `variant` object through your non-`explicit` constructor:

```
template<typename T> variant(T value)
```

You can see this happening if you delete the copy constructor or mark your constructor as explicit:

```
variant(const variant&) = delete;
template<typename T> explicit variant(T value)
```

GCC says:

```
test.cpp:100:14: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’
   var_test_2 = std::string("Hello again !");
```

If you change your assignment operator to use `const` references then your code works as desired. I'd additionally suggest marking your constructor as `explicit`, otherwise you run into really subtle problems like this one.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/41b8db727b48fd22)

---

A small aside: `__get_storage` is a reserved name since it starts with two underscores. You should not use it in your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and your last advice. I begin to know C++, but there are still a lot of subtleties I have trouble with…

Comment: This answer needs to mention the rule of five/zero.

Comment: @Yakk Yes maybe I need to implement by hand the copy / move constructors.

Comment: @Boiethios You implemented a destructor.  You must consider the copy/move operations.  This could be `=default`, `=delete`, or implementing them (and usually not `=default`).  You cannot simply neglect them, you will get (as shown above) bugs.